# Aligning different font sizes on the same line of text so it looks nice?

Tags: css, text, alignment

Basically, I want to have an h1 and a p element on the same line, but the alignment is off a lot (meaning the H1 is higher than the P and looks crappy) and I've never had to do anything like this with css before!

I've thrown together a jsfiddle to accompany this, here is the code:

```
<h1 style="float:left;display:inline;">"Hi!</h1><p style="float:left;display:inline;">I'm James, and I <strong>LOVE</strong> building clean, fast and (most importantly) effective websites. Oh, and I also know a thing or two about computers.</p><h1 style="float:left;display:inline">"</h1>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9H8xE/

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show a sample image of what you want it to look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some advice before answer:

1. P tag is meant to create a new paaragraph, so if you do not need that use span tag instead.
2. Try to avoid inline styles, use CSS selectors.

http://jsfiddle.net/9H8xE/1/

Try this and let me know if it `works`

**HTML:**

```
<h1 >"Hi!</h1><p>I'm James, and I <strong>LOVE</strong> building clean, fast and (most importantly) effective websites. Oh, and I also know a thing or two about computers.</p><h1>"</h1>
```

**CSS:**

```
p
{
    display:inline;
}
h1{
    display:inline
}
```

Comment: @MrS1ck is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Perfect! I'm mostly self taught, and didn't know that the difference between P and Span. Today I learned and it worked perfectly! THANK YOU!

Comment: @MrS1ck you are welcome, if you have any other question Let me know :)

Comment: The text of the answer does not mention the real problem with the original code: `float: left`. The code given in the answer is essentially the same as in the question, just `float: left` omitted.

Answer (score 2):

The technical problem with the code in the question is that `float: left` prevents `display: inline` from taking effect, [setting `display` to `block`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo) instead, so remove all the `float: left` declarations.

A different issue is that you have the closing quotation mark as the content of an `h1` element after the `p` element. This is very illogical. The technical implication is that this character will appear in the font size of `h1`, causing uneven line spacing unless you set `h1` font size to the same as `p` font size. You need to decide what you want: why would you want to a have a large-size closing quote after normal-size text, and if you do, how should it be rendered?